# How do I calculate the bite force of a mechanical gripper jaw? Which software can be used to simulate the same?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I plan to mount a gripper mechanism on a drone to grip a payload. How do I calculate the force generated by the gripper to hold a given weight. What simulation software can be used to simulate the bite of this jaw and get the force

Comment: The force will depend on the input and the leverage

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the gripper mechanism an the properties of the objects you want to lift, you can do it by hand calculation (ideal case). It would be much easier to give you advice if you gave information about the structure and material of object to be lifted (like rigid solids, compliant foamy things, or bulk like sand).

**Now I'm assuming a rigid load object and a gripping mechanism to hold it using friction only.** You can use sum of forces/moment to calculate the forces your gripper excerts on the load. These are usually normal forces $F_N$ acting perpendicular to the object and causing a maximum friction of $F_{fric} = \mu \cdot F_N$. This should be well above the weight of the object $m_L\cdot g$ since this is the limit your gripper can *'bite'*. Friction coefficients can vary widely and what works on a sunny day does not neccessarily work on rainy days or when covered in morning dew. As a standard loosely connected to this topic I recommend EN13155-"Load-Carrying Equipment". There you can find information and safety factors.

**Since you asked for software.** For typical gripping mechanisms I'd reccomend hand calcualtion first. Elsewise you have no feeling for the numbers you get by engineering software.

- Multibody Dynamics Software MBD (for gripper mechanism, solid loads, little compliance, usually 3d modelling software, fast multibody solvers, expensive except for students) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multibody_system)

  - ANSYS MBD
  - RecurDyn
  - Simpack
  - Adams
  - MBDyn (free software)
  - Comsol
  - ...
- General purpose modelling tools (for gripper mechanism and solid load, little compliance, multiple domains e.g. electrical, hydraulics and mechanism, mathematical approach, harder to get to results if there are no good libaries for your job)

  - OpenModelica (free)
  - Dymola
  - ANSYS Simplorer
  - Matlab/Simulink
  - MapleSim
  - ...
- If your goods and/ or your gripping mechanism is compliant (speak: deformations are of major importance) you probably have to use Finite Element Analysis tools (maybe coupled with software above, depending on your goals) FEA software like ANSYS can handle large deformations, semi-rigid assemblies, nonlinear material, frictional contact and gives really good results. BUT it can be very slow since the solver for FEA is different from MBD. This can still be a viable approach if you make good assumptions/simplications  for your model and if your assembly is lightweight. (I'd personally go for ANSYS since I have kind of love/hate relation with it ;-) )

  - ANSYS
  - Patran
  - Comsol
  - Code Aster (free)
  - ... see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_element_software_packages) for more

For background reading and Matlab I recommend "Grundlagen und Methodik der Mehrkörpersimulation" but don't know if an English version exists. For bulk goods you can use Discrete Element Software (DEM, [Wikipedia here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_element_method)) like ANSYS RockyDEM to simulate the behaviour of sand, coal and so on...

Hope this helps a bit. Clarifications welcome.

Comment: You wrote the book on the question, +1.  Just a few more examples: scissors lifters which grab tighter than the weight of the load by just geometry of the teeth, magnet lifters, and rope baskets, etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking that time out. That has really helped in giving that significant initial push ;) The object I need to lift is a rigid cylinder roughly weighing 500 gm. As you have mentioned I need to find Ffric=μ⋅Fn, But how to calculate Fn? as for the 'μ', I think I can get that from standard tables for a material.

Comment: @AdSinc You can do it the other way round: So you have like 5 N of weight $G$, so you need $G/ \mu$ of clamping force. This is *roughly* around 50 N. Then define your travel on the gripper, so you can dimension the motor and the required lever/transmission. This depends if you have differing object diameters and how well you can position your drone.

Be prepared to run some circles, but this is normal in engineering if you want to create something new (at least new for you ;-) ) And don't forget to mark it as answered if it  fits your question. Maybe I'll add the comments to the answer ...

Comment: Thanks a ton! everything helped :)